# Is possible to develop .NET app to run tests in MetaTrader5 and iterate over the results?

Tags: .net, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

Is there a way to develop a .NET app that

1. Will run a particular EA with parameters
2. From results tab run top(5) results and take one of them which lower concurrent loses?
3. And save this one to file - (this is easy)
4. Then next parameters for the same ea?

Is it possible?

Does anybody have some .NET code that can share for me to start with ?

If someone known that this is not possible only some RPA-clicker etc may try to do this then please also post this kind of answer

Thanks and regards!